# Bash if statement with Y/N

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement

I have this code below which is part of a much longer script I'm working on to help automate some sysadmin tasks on fresh servers but I can't seem to get the logic working for this IF statement.

```
apt-get -y install ${CORE_TOOLS[*]}

printf "\nWould you like to install some \033[0;32moptional\033[0m tools in addition to the core build toolkit? [Y/N]\n"
read -r -p answer
if [[ $answer = "Y" ]] ; then
    apt-get -y install ${EXTRA_TOOLS[*]}
fi

........
```

Once the user types Y and hits enter it's supposed to execute the statement with apt-get, but simply does nothing and continues to execute the rest of the script without throwing any errors.

```
Processing triggers for ca-certificates (20141019+deb8u2) ...
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs... 174 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d....done.

Would you like to install some optional tools in addition to the core build toolkit? [Y/N]
answerY
Cloning into 'testcookie-nginx-module'...
remote: Counting objects: 294, done.
remote: Total 294 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 294
Receiving objects: 100% (294/294), 253.53 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
```

Any idea why this might be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest to remove read‘s option `-p` or add text:

```
read -r -p "foo" answer
```

See: `help read`

Comment: YES! You did it! Also codeforester's reply was quite helpful too, but you got there fast, appreciated. :)

Answer (score 4):

The issue is with the `read` call:

```
read -r -p answer
```

would treat `answer` as the prompt and store the value read in the variable `REPLY` (which is the default).

You can change it to:

```
read -r answer
```

Or, combine the `printf` and `read` into one statement, passing the message as an argument to `-p` option of `read`.  Note that you need ANSI C quoting, `$''`:

```
read -r -p $'\nWould you like to install some \033[0;32moptional\033[0m tools in addition to the core build toolkit? [Y/N]\n' answer
```

Comment: Thank you! Cyrus also provided the correct answer but this provided a great explanation! I appreciate the fast reply! <3